# how to configure svn client on OSX for SASL authentication?

Tags: macos, svn, sasl

Our svn server uses SASL for authentication. We use tortoisesvn client on windows and svn command line on Linux and both work fine.

We recently added a Mac OSX (running Yosemite) but the svn client in there is unable to team up with the svn server. On the client I see errors like:

```
 $ svn ls svn://svnhost/myrepo
 svn: E210007: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svnhost/myrepo'
 svn: E210007: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism
```

while on the svn server side, the logs show lots of

```
3101 2015-08-11T02:39:01.487416Z 192.168.0.2 - - ERR - 0 210002 Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Server conf:

```
[sasl]
use-sasl = true
min-encryption = 128
max-encryption = 256
```

and

```
SASLAUTHD_AUTHMECH=pam
```

On the Mac OS I installed brew and then colorsvn, but it does nothing different from the preinstalled svn. What else is required to use svn on Mac?

Comment: Any fix? I am having the exact same issue. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so for anyone else having this problem, this is how I was able to get this working:

```
Installed MacPorts
Installed Sasl from Macports (sudo port install cyrus-sasl2)
Installed SVN from Macports (sudo port install subversion)
```

BOOM! Yahtzee!

Comment: Thanks. I had to get an older port for subversion but that was easy!